# Firebase updates doesn't change in screen (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

in my project, i have a button that will change some value from firebase, what i am facing is that although i am using **setState** and **futureBuilder**, the changes doesn't really appear until i do a hot restart, what's the issue?

code:

```
Center(
                       child: 
                       snapshot.data.docs[i].data()['isWatched'] == false?
                       IconButton(
                           onPressed: () {
                             setState(() async{
                               await watchLaterRef.doc(documentId).update({

                                 'isWatched': true

                               });
                             });
                           },
                           icon: Icon(
                             Icons.check_box,
                             size: 50,
                             color: Colors.yellow,
                           ))
                           :
                           IconButton(
                           onPressed: () {
                             setState(() async{
                               await watchLaterRef.doc(documentId).update({

                                 'isWatched': false

                               });
                             });
                           },
                           icon: Icon(
                             Icons.check_box,
                             size: 50,
                             color: Colors.green,
                           ))

                     )
```

Comment: Share the build() method codes

Comment: share full code to get better answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't use **`async`** and **`await`** with **`setState`**.